# Highlights package name and import in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import, package, intellij-14

Package name highlights in red due to correct directory structure.
First highlight is package tech.tablesaw.plotly; //This is correct directory name
Second import tech.tablesaw.examples.AbstractExample; comes from core [tablesaw-core] module.
This should work fine especialy that 
import tech.tablesaw.api.NumberColumn;
imports correctly.

pom.xml from tablesaw-jsplot

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>tech.tablesaw</groupId>
    <artifactId>tablesaw-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.30.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have the `plotty` directory incorrectly marked as a [**source root**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#folder-categories) while this directory is a part of the your packages. You need to have the `java` directory marked as a **source root**.

If `jsplot` is a Maven project - make sure the `jsplot` module (and all Maven other modules) is added into IDE as a Maven project (you can add it from pom.xml file context menu) and [re-import project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_dependency) in Maven tool window.

If `jsplot` is not a Maven project just mark the `java` directory as a source root manually.